# install flask-pymongo with pip- python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, pip, installation, pymongo, flask-pymongo

hellow everyone,
i tried to install PyMongo package with pip( i hope that is the way to do it). [its a part of a login system]

my command line was:

```
C:/Python36/Scripts/pip install PyMongo
```

But, when i put it in the command line i got

```
the system cannot find the file specificied.
```

And the import line in the code was:

```
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
```

Do someone knows what should i do?
Thanks!!

Comment: What do you get when you run:
`cd /Python36/Scripts/` and `dir`

Comment: Shouldn't the command line be `C:\Python36\Scripts\pip install PyMongo`?

Answer (score 0):

[Flask-PyMongo](https://flask-pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a different package than [PyMongo](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/). It looks like you've only installed PyMongo, but are trying to use Flask-PyMongo in your application. You should run `C:/Python36/Scripts/pip install Flask-PyMongo` to install Flask-PyMongo.

Answer (score 0):

You installed PyMongo and tried to import PyMongo from `flask_pymongo`.

PyMongo is a package to work with MongoDB. To make this work more efficient, Flask just made an extension named "Flask-PyMongo". So, we can directly import "Flask-PyMongo" and start working with MongoDB in a very efficient way.

You can think "Flask-PyMongo" as a wrapper of "PyMongo".